# How to Return Number of Both Incoming and Outgoing Relationships for Every Node

Tags: neo4j

I wish to count the number of incoming relationships and the number of outgoing relationships for each node (this gives some insight wrt connectivity).

I can get the number of incoming (or outgoing) using a query like:

```
MATCH outg=(a)-->(b)
RETURN a.name, labels(a) AS Stereotype,count(rels(outg)) AS out
ORDER BY out DESC
```

This works.

If, however I try adding incoming relationships:

```
MATCH outg=(a)-->(b), incom=(c)-->(a)
RETURN a.name, labels(a) AS Stereotype,count(rels(outg)) AS out, count(rels(incom)) AS in
ORDER BY out DESC
```

then it doesn't produce what I'd expect. In this case both the incoming and outgoing counts are the same and much higher than either on its own (so some sort of multiplication going on).

How should it be done and what's wrong with the logic used in the second case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I voted for Nicole's and Sam's answers.

However I think there is much more simpler :

```
MATCH (a)
RETURN id(a), labels(a) as stereotype, 
size((a)-->()) as out, size((a)<--()) as in
```

You can change `id(a)` with whatever property you want.

---

**UPDATE FOR NEO4J 5**

```
MATCH (a)
RETURN 
  COUNT { (a)-->() } AS out,
  COUNT { (a)<--() } AS in
```

Comment: I totally forgot about SIZE. This is the best answer.

Comment: I agree this is the best answer.

Comment: That certainly works. Adding ORDER BY (out+in) DESC returns the most highly-connected nodes first.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this. Assume you have the movie dataset loaded:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]-(b)
RETURN COALESCE(a.name, a.title), LABELS(a) AS Label,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STARTNODE(r) = a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS outgoing,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STARTNODE(r) = b THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS incoming
ORDER BY outgoing DESC
```

You can see its results here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/6ebvy8

Answer (score 2):

This query should work for you. The logic is pretty straightforward.

```
MATCH (a)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-->(b)
WITH a, LENGTH(COLLECT(b)) AS out
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-->(a)
RETURN a.name, labels(a) AS Stereotype, out, LENGTH(COLLECT(c)) AS in 
ORDER BY out DESC;
```

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=7doaf4) that demonstrates the query.

One of reasons your query did not work properly is because it was using the `COUNT()` function, which returns the number of rows -- not the length (or size) of a collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH outg=(a)-[og]->(b), incom=(c)-[ic]->(a) RETURN id(a), labels(a) AS Stereotype,count(og) AS out, count(ic) AS in ORDER BY out DESC
```

Comment: This is not correct. `a` will only be matched if it has at least one incoming and outgoing relationship.

Comment: It doesn't produce a correct result - seems to be the same as the original erroneous query.